# SwiftUI : How I can push my view above to use textfield?(halfASheet, TextEditor)

Tags: swiftui, keyboard

```
import SwiftUI
import HalfASheet

struct FolderListView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var vm : FolderListViewModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var folderName : String = ""
    @State private var showAddSheet : Bool = false
    @State private var showAlert : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            NavigationView{
                ZStack{
                    if vm.folders.count == 0 {
                        NoFolderView()
                    } else {
                        List {
                            ForEach(vm.folders) { folder in
                                NavigationLink(destination: {
                                    MemoListView(folder: folder)
                                }, label: {
                                    FolderRowView(folder: folder)
                                })
                            }
                            .onDelete(perform: vm.deleteFolder)
                        }//list
                        .listStyle(.plain)
                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    }
                }
                    .navigationTitle("Folders ")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showAddSheet.toggle()
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "plus")
                            })
                        }
                    }
        }
            HalfASheet(isPresented: $showAddSheet) {
                halfSheetView
            }
            .height(.proportional(0.25))
            .contentInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
            }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    
    private var halfSheetView : some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("폴더명을 입력하세요 ")
                .font(.headline.bold())
            TextField("Insert folder's name", text: $folderName)
                .autocapitalization(.none)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)

            Divider()
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            Button(action: {
                if vm.checkFolderNameCount(folderName: folderName) {
                    vm.addNewFolder(folderName: folderName)
                    self.folderName = ""
                    self.showAddSheet.toggle()
                } else {
                    self.showAlert.toggle()
                }
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Save".uppercased())
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
                    .frame(height : 50)
                    .background(Color.accentColor)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            })
            .alert(isPresented : $showAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Naming Error "), message: Text("Letters for folder's name is too short. Please check it one more time."), dismissButton: .cancel())
            }
            Spacer()
        }//vst
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
        .padding()
    }
    
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FolderListView()
    }
}
```

1. this code is about my 'halfASheet'(library) code first.

   import SwiftUI

   struct NewMemoView: View {

   ```
    let folder : FolderModel
    let memo : MemoModel?

    @EnvironmentObject var vm : FolderListViewModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    @State private var title : String = ""
    @State private var content : String = ""
    @State private var color : Color = .yellow.opacity(0.3)
    @State private var showAlert : Bool = false
    @State private var pickedImportance : String = "Easy "
    @State private var isEditMode : Bool = false
    let importances = ["Easy ", "Normal ☀️", "Important "]

    init(memo : MemoModel?, folder : FolderModel) {
        self.folder = folder
        self.memo = memo
        if let memo = memo {
            _title = State(initialValue: memo.title)
            _content = State(initialValue: memo.content)
            _color = State(initialValue: memo.color)
            _pickedImportance = State(initialValue: memo.isImportant)
            _isEditMode = State(initialValue: true)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header : Text("Title ")) {
                TextField("Input the title", text: $title)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
            }

            Section(header : Text("Importance ✅")) {
                Picker("", selection: $pickedImportance) {
                    ForEach(importances, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            }

            Section(header : Text("Content ✏️")) {
                TextEditor(text: $content)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .frame(maxWidth : .infinity)
                    .frame(height : UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.3)
            }
            Section(header : Text("Select Color")) {
                ColorPicker("Memo Color", selection: $color, supportsOpacity: false)
            }

            Button(action: {

                if isEditMode {
                    if vm.checkMemoStatus(title: title, content: content) {
                        vm.editMemo(folder: folder, memo: memo!, title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: pickedImportance)
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } else {
                        self.showAlert.toggle()
                    }
                } else {
                    if vm.checkMemoStatus(title: title, content: content) {
                        vm.addMemo(folder: folder, title: title, content: content, color: color, isImportant: pickedImportance)
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    } else {
                        self.showAlert.toggle()
                    }
                }

            }, label: {
                Text(isEditMode ? "Edit".uppercased() : "save".uppercased())
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
            })
            .alert(isPresented : $showAlert) {
                Alert(title: Text("Warning "), message: Text("Check your title and content, please."), dismissButton: .cancel())
            }
        }//form
        .navigationTitle("Add Memo ")
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
    }
   ```

   }
2. This next code is about form with textfield and texteditor.
   (This screenshot is about halfSheet)

[image]

What I want to do is that when I tapped the halfsheet's textfield,
I want to push my view to up.

I tried the use scrollview, but this is not working.
How I can handle this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your value on height when you focused on textField

```
@State var isEditing = false

TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { edit in
                        self.isEditing = edit
                    })

HalfASheet(isPresented: $showAddSheet) {
                halfSheetView
            }
            .height(.proportional(isEditing ? 0.25 : 0.75))
```